# Flutter - How to display screen info when pressed button

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, tabview

I'm trying to create a screen where you can see some post in one button and others post in the other button, both buttons are inside the same screen **like this**:

[image: example]

Is there a widget that allows me to recreate it

Comment: do you mean like [this](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/tabs) TabBar with TabBarView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use TabBar Widget with two Tabs inside it
here is an example

```
body: const TabBarView(
children: [
  Icon(Icons.directions_car),
  Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
  ],
),
```

Comment: don't forget to use DefaultTabController with length of 2